# Can I perform a one-to-many join query using a QuerydslPredicate?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-starter

I see in [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-querydsl-multiple-tables) that providing paths as part of the predicate can generate a join:

`get("/users?address.country=Spain")` generates:

```
select user0_.id as id1_1_, 
       user0_.name as name2_1_ 
from user user0_ 
      cross join address address1_ 
where user0_.id=address1_.user_id 
      and address1_.country='Spain'
```

In the example above though I see that the relationship is one-to-one.

My question is: is it possible to provide **a path that goes from one-to-many in order to create an implicit outer join**

e.g. in the [above guide example](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-querydsl-multiple-tables#Testing) would I be able to provide: `/users?address.country=Spain` if users had one-to-many relationship with address, and get back something like the following?:

```
user1-address1
user1-address2
user2-address3
user2-address4
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question, sort of, at least in terms of joining. I don't know what you mean by "as part of a predicate". I encourage you to research and post what you have tried before asking questions poorly on SO.

[JPA Criteria: QuerySyntaxException for left join on treat entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362329/jpa-criteria-querysyntaxexception-for-left-join-on-treat-entity)

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it is more clear now.